# Why does my particle hair look so patchy?

Tags: rendering, particles, shaders, hair

Particle hair seem to have a weird behavior. Following image shows my guides:

[image]

And here is the render:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern

Add a small amount of randomness to the vertices to avoid that.

Comment: It actually works !

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you've set too small *root radius* and *edge*. Considering *Diameter scale*, it becomes 0.01 * 0.01 = 0.0001 which I believe is pretty physically accurate but almost invisible if the rest of the character is not scaled to 1.7m height. Try to increase root radius.

Comment: I have set my character to real world size,the thing is not the size of the hair but the inconsistent look on different parts of every hair strand.